# New Tabs in Chrome 57 Are Grey and Sad — How to Troubleshoot?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, tabs

Quiet often during my work Chrome becomes broken:

1. New tabs are grey and empty and sometimes sad.
2. All extensions crash if I try to reload them.
3. Old tabs continue to work normally.
4. Restarting Chrome helps but the issue happens again and again.

I develop one extension, so I reload it often.

**How to troubleshoot this or locate the reason behind the bug?**

Here are SOME extensions that I use:

- Blank New Tab Page 1.0.6
- Chrome extension source viewer 1.5
- COPY URL 1.7
- Google +1 Button 1.3.0.325
- Runet Censorship Bypass 0.0.0.27
- uBlock Origin 1.11.4

[image: Sad Tabs in Chrome]

### Solution

I switched to ["Empty New Tab Page"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-new-tab-page/dpjamkmjmigaoobjbekmfgabipmfilij) extension that doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first guess I'd say it's likely the new tab extension is crashing. (As it's new tabs that are failing to render).

That said, the way to troubleshoot it would be the 'standard' for chrome - create a new profile, and then enable each extension one by one, until you find which one causes the crashes.

Comment: I analysed _"Blank New Tab Page"_ sources and haven't found anything complicated or suspicious — very simple extension. But thanks, I'll try turning it off.

Comment: @ilyaigpetrov you looked at the source code for the extension? Does google/chrome publish the source code for all their extensions somewhere easy to find, or was that particular extension's author just kind enough to post the source on his webpage?

Comment: @Xen2050 Blank new tab page is among [sample extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) (a different extension). I don't believe it's the author's intent to restrict access to the sources. Sometimes I forget to attach license to my sources as well if they are small like this extension.